# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'faces-config'

Tags: eclipse, jsf, xsd, faces-config

I created a JSF 2.1 project in Eclipse. While building the project, it shows the following error markers:

> - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element `'faces-config'`.
> - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document `'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd'`, because
>
>   1. could not find the document;
>   2. the document could not be read;
>   3. the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Your own solution seems to bee very specific. The default tag should look like this

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
          version="2.1">
    ....
</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, it seems there is no xsd file in the given URL.

So changed the url to https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.1.13/jsf-api/doc/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd.

It is working fine.